# Accelerometer values go to 0 every time I move the device

Tags: android, accelerometer, sensors

I am trying to figure out how the accelerometer sensor work. I have a service which is started by my MainActivity and logs the sensor's data in the console. I followed the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#values) recommendation (eliminated the "force of gravity" in the sensor's readings). Now to the point, I am observing strange behaviour every time I move the device. Say it is laying on a table and I move it perpendicular with the top of the device facing up like that

[image]

and the readings go from all zero (XYZ) to that:
[image]

As you can see from the accelerometer's readings as soon as I hold my device to the up mentioned position steal the readings go back to zeros. Can somebody explain that behaviour to be please. Why the X, Y and Z value go back go zero (provided I hold the device steal).

This is my service code that logs the data:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // alpha is calculated as t / (t + dT)
    // with t, the low-pass filter's time-constant
    // and dT, the event delivery rate

    final float alpha = (float) 0.8;


    gravity[0] = alpha * gravity[0] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[0];
    gravity[1] = alpha * gravity[1] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[1];
    gravity[2] = alpha * gravity[2] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[2];

    linear_acceleration[0] = event.values[0] - gravity[0];
    linear_acceleration[1] = event.values[1] - gravity[1];
    linear_acceleration[2] = event.values[2] - gravity[2];




    double x = Math.abs(Math.round(linear_acceleration[0]));
    double y = Math.abs(Math.round(linear_acceleration[1]));;
    double z = Math.abs(Math.round(linear_acceleration[2]));

    Log.d(TAG, "TimeStamp: " + event.timestamp + " X: " + x + " Y: " + y + " Z: " + z);

}
```

Comment: The linear acceleration is pretty small and thus the value of Math.round will be all zero. Take out the Math.round.

Comment: Thank you! I will see what happens :P